# What is the correct template parameter/argument for operator[] as a member function?

Tags: c++, templates, parameters, arguments

In an attempt to call a function template which accepts a type and a parameter/argument of that type as the template parameters/arguments, compiler gives an error which is not produced with similar parameters/arguments. So I was wondering what is the correct parameters/arguments in case of calling the function templates for the member function "operator[]const" of a vector class!

Consider this piece of code:

```
class test_class{
    public:
    int member;
    int& operator[](size_t) {return member;}
    const int& operator[](size_t) const{return member;}
};
typedef std::vector<int> vector_type;

typedef const int&(test_class::* OK_type)(size_t)const;
typedef const int&(vector_type::* not_OK_type)(size_t)const;

static constexpr OK_type OK_pointer = &test_class::operator[];
static constexpr not_OK_type not_OK_pointer = &vector_type::operator[];

template<typename t__, t__>
void function(){}
```

The above code is alright now consider the main function:

```
int main() {
    function<OK_type, OK_pointer>();
    function<not_OK_type, not_OK_pointer>();
    return 0;
}
```

The first call of the function template is OK but not the second one.
The error which compiler produce is:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘function<not_OK_type, not_OK_pointer>()’
note: candidate: ‘template<class t__, t__ <anonymous> > void function()’
note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
error: ‘const int& (std::vector<int>::*)(size_t) const{((const int& (std::vector<int>::*)(size_t) const)std::vector<int>::operator[]), 0}’ is not a valid template argument for type ‘const int& (std::vector<int>::*)(long unsigned int) const’
function<not_OK_type, not_OK_pointer>();
note: it must be a pointer-to-member of the form ‘&X::Y’
```

Interestingly even if the function template was formed as:

```
template<auto>
void function(){}
```

it would cause the same result.

I must add that in the case of non const version, error is the same (for `std::vector`).

So I am wondering

A: what is wrong?

B: Considering that if there was a mismatch between the `not_OK_type` and     `&vector_type::operator[]`, then compiler would also give an error in case of:

```
static constexpr not_OK_type not_OK_pointer = &vector_type::operator[];
```

Is there a difference between types that can be used as constexpr and the type that can be used as a template parameter/argument?

Comment: gcc (GCC) 8.3.1 20190223. Also with -std=c++2a

Comment: For me compiler is OK with the first case, it is just wrong for the not_OK case. Do you think there is a fundamental error with my template usage or do you think it is a compiler error?

Comment: @P.W At least first call works. See this. https://wandbox.org/permlink/AywSwCjDV7T91bHI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is `typedef const int&(vector_type::* not_OK_type)(size_t)const;`.

If you see `stl_vector.h` ([here](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_vector.h)), the operator[] is declared as `noexcept` at line 1040.

But in the declaration of `not_OK_type` variable, `noexcept` is not present. That's why the compiler complains.

For getting rid of compilation error, add `noexcept` to `not_OK_type` variable. Like this:

```
typedef const int&(vector_type::* not_OK_type)(size_t)const noexcept;
```

Working code:

```
#include <vector>

class test_class{
    public:
    int member;
    int& operator[](size_t) {return member;}
    const int& operator[](size_t) const{return member;}
};
typedef std::vector<int> vector_type;

typedef const int&(test_class::* OK_type)(size_t)const;
typedef const int&(vector_type::* not_OK_type)(size_t)const noexcept;

static constexpr OK_type OK_pointer = &test_class::operator[];
static constexpr not_OK_type not_OK_pointer = &vector_type::operator[];

template<typename t__, t__>
void function(){}

int main() {
    function<OK_type, OK_pointer>();
    function<not_OK_type, not_OK_pointer>();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Very nice, Thank you. Do you know why the compiler is OK with the type definition(without noexcept) for the constants but not for the template parameters?

Comment: @AKL I think that's because in case of templates, it is strictly checked at compile time whether the type is exactly same.

Comment: @AKL In the earlier code, `not_OK_type` was not declared  as `noexcept` which meant that the function to which it will point **may** throw. But the address of function which was assigned to it was `noexcept` which meant that it won't throw any exception. I think that's why compiler might have ignored that case because it is not harmful if a function doesn't throw when it is expected to throw by the pointer which points to it. Vice Versa can be an issue though.

Comment: @AKL If you feel this answered your question, please consider accepting. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

@Kunal Puri, provided a correct answer for the the section A of the question.

As for the section B of the question, I guess the clue can be found in one **exception** that applies when **converted constant expression** used as template argument for a non-type template parameter.

According to (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression), a converted constant expression under certain condition and specifically in case of *conversion of pointer to noexcept function to pointer to function* is a constant expression. Which explains why compiler did not produce an error in case of:

```
static constexpr not_OK_type not_OK_pointer = &vector_type::operator[];
```

However according to (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters), this type of converted constant expression can not be used as a pointer to non-static data members(and maybe also a pointer to non-static member functions) for a non-type template parameter.

This exception might be the source of conflict between types that can be used as **constexpr** and as **template argument**, although statements in the later source are vague and not directly linked to the case.